# (iOS 7) cellForRowAtIndexPath not get called, but heightForRowAtIndexPath get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I tried to optimize an UITableView, where it should display the end of the list on startup.
After storing the database it calls `[tableView reloadData]` out of a background thread and afterwards on the main thread `[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPositionBottom animated:NO]`.
I work as well with estimatedRowHeight, so heightForRowAtIndexPath just get called for visible items. (but it doesn't make any difference for this issue if I deactivate it)

Running this on an iOS 8 Device (iPhone 6, iPhone 5S) everything works fine.
From bottom (last item) to last visible item on the screen `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` get called.
On an iOS 7 Device (iPhone 4S) just `heightForRowAtIndexPath` get called and no item on the TableView is visible.
If I scroll two times `cellForRowAtIndexPath` get called and the items appear.
Setting `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` to `animated:YES` doesn't make any difference.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Without `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` everything works fine as well, but the list is at the top. (missed goal)

**EDIT 2:**
After returning `(CGFloat)100` for `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` it works. But depending on the height of the items sometimes it doesn't scroll to the end of the list. Therefor I returned for the first 8 items `(CGFloat)500` and afterwards `(CGFloat)100` (this gives me the error I described at the beginning). Any other workaround to get to the bottom of a list?

Comment: Follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044025/bottom-up-uitableview-with-different-item-height-scroll-to-end