# Bottom-up UITableView with different item height scroll to end

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I have a UITableView with different item height.
At the beginning the user should see the last items (that are at the end of the list) and should be able to scroll manually to the top.

To get to the end of the list I use `[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPositionBottom animated:NO]` on the main thread after I called `[tableView reloadData]` on a background process.
To speed it up and to get to the real end I use `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` and I return for the first 8 items `(CGFloat)500` and for the other items `(CGFloat)100`.
Using `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` avoids the call for `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for every item in the list (it could be a very long list).

With iOS 8 (iPhone 4S, 5S, 6) everything works fine, but with iOS 7 (iPhone 4S) just `heightForRowAtIndexPath` get called but not `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so there is no item displayed until I start to scroll.
Returning `(CGFloat)100` for every `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`-call avoids this, but it doesn't scroll to the real end of the list and compaired to the iOS 8 iPhone 4S version it is pretty slow.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with a better implementation of `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`.
There we calculate with some simple calculations a better estimated height for the first 50 items, so we get values pretty close to the real height.
For the other items we return an average from the first calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could simply reload the visible cells after you scroll down....

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] 
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: How do I know, which cells are visible?

Comment: `[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]` returns the visible cells. It's a UITableView property

Answer (score -1):

Since you know you want to scroll to the bottom, you could use

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Then you don't need to calculate cell heights and add heights of section headers and footers.

Comment: Yes, my apologies.  I did a poor job of answering that one.